# What is the formula for total reactance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Total Reactance is the sum of capacitive reactance and inductive reactance. So, it should be given by the formula

$$X = X(L) + X(C) \, ..$$

However, in some sources it is

$$X = X(L) - X(C)$$

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is correct for reactances defined as $X_L=\frac{V_{rms}}{I_{rms}}=2\pi fL$ and $X_C=\frac{V_{rms}}{I_{rms}}=1/2\pi fC$. Imagine an inductor and a capacitor connected in series across a (sinusoidal) alternating voltage. The current 'through' the capacitor will be the same as that through the inductor at any instant. But the pd across the inductor will lead the current by $\pi/2$ (a quarter of a cycle), whereas the pd across the capacitor will lag behind the current by $\pi/2$. Therefore the pds across the two components will be in antiphase. The pds will therefore  tend to cancel, as will the reactances.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitive and inductive reactances are the magnitudes (scalar quantities) of capacitive and inductive impedances (two dimensional vector quantities) which, in the complex plane, are $+jX_{L}$ and $-jX_{C}$. So your second equation is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be helpful if you please clarify why is capacitive reactance negative and inductive reactance is positive

Comment: Because they act  opposite (180 $^o$ apart) to one another. In a capacitor current leads voltage by 90$^o$ while in an inductor current lags voltage by 90$^o$.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be correct depending on the convention.

If you defined your reactances as complex quantities (that is, as the complex impedances of the perfect capacitance resp. inductance), then the first is correct, if you define them as the absolute value of the complex impedance, then the second equation will be correct.

(Note: Which one of $X_C$ and $X_L$ is positive is purely conventional, all equations of complex circuit analysis remain true if you *consistently* apply $j \mapsto -j$).